# ZeroMQ API seems to ignore my PUB's

Tags: python, camera, usb, zeromq

I'm hoping someone might have some more experience with **`Smart Shooter 3`** and it's API, **`ZeroMQ`**.

`ZeroMQ` seems to be a different version of MQTT, but essentually works in the same way with publishing and subscribing to topics.

`Smart Shooter 3` is a program designed to control settings/options and shoot to take pictures with a DSLR camera through an USB connection.

I'm currently trying add additional functionality to this project and I'm trying to listen to this `ZeroMQ` server for the command to take a picture:

```
import json
import datetime
import argparse
import zmq

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("smartshooter-listen.py")
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet",
                        action="store_true",
                        default=False,
                        help="enable quiet mode for reduced logging")
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--nopings",
                        action="store_true",
                        default=False,
                        help="filter out ping messages")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--publisher",
                        default="tcp://127.0.0.1:54543",
                        metavar="ENDPOINT",
                        help="specify ZMQ address of Smart Shooter publisher")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    context = zmq.Context()

    sub_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sub_socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
    sub_socket.connect(args.publisher)

    while (True):
        raw = sub_socket.recv()
        str_msg = raw.decode("utf-8")
        json_msg = json.loads(str_msg)
        if args.nopings and json_msg["msg_id"] == "NetworkPingMsg":
            continue
        print("{0}: {1}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), json_msg["msg_id"]))
        if not args.quiet:
            print(str_msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I connect to the `ZeroMQ` server running on `Smart Shooter 3`, it gives a **`msg_type Request, msg_id NetworkPingMsg`** every 5 seconds or so. When I press <kbd>**shoot**</kbd> a picture, it updates that it took a picture at what ISO value, etc, however, no **'Request'** to shoot a picture is given.

I also found a script to take pictures:

```
import sys
import json
import argparse
import zmq

def send_shoot(socket):
    req = {}
    req["msg_type"] = "Request"
    req["msg_id"] = "ShootMsg"
    req["msg_ref_num"] = 0
    req["CameraSelection"] = "All"
    socket.send_string(json.dumps(req))
    rep = socket.recv()
    str_msg = rep.decode("utf-8")
    json_msg = json.loads(str_msg)
    return json_msg["Result"]

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("smartshooter-trigger.py")
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--reqrep",
                        default="tcp://127.0.0.1:54544",
                        metavar="ENDPOINT",
                        help="specify ZMQ address of Smart Shooter request/reply server")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    context = zmq.Context()

    req_socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    req_socket.connect(args.reqrep)

    if not send_shoot(req_socket):
        print("Failed to send trigger message", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I use this, however, the DSLR shoots a picture. While listening to this feed on `ZeroMQ`, I now see the shoot picture command.

Is it at all possible the information is not being sent over `ZeroMQ` but over USB only?

What I'm really asking is, is there anyone that might know where or **how I can find out the code for respond/see when a picture is requested over `ZeroMQ`.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### ZeroMQ API is not to be blamed

Supposing your statements are supported by a DSLR-under-Test experiments done as reported, the solution goes in this direction:

1. There are several **ZeroMQ** **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**atterns exposed for different modes of a distributed processing system's communications:
   **`PUB`** using **`tcp://127.0.0.1:54543`** transport-class ( user configurable )
   **`REP`** using **`tcp://127.0.0.1:54544`** transport-class, but on another port ( configurable )

---

2. Sofware can **`.connect()`** it's local **`SUB`** **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern counterparty to the exposed **`PUB`** access point ( as per item 1. above ) to listen and receive ( due to `.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")` method called ) all the messages distributed from the `PUB` node ( which are `utf-8` encoded `JSON`-wrapped data-structures )

---

3. Software also can **`.connect()`** it's local **`REQ`** **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern counterparty to the other port, exposed as a public access point ( as per item 1. above ) to send properly formatted requests ( by a call to **`send_shoot( socket )`**
   where **`socket`** has to be:
    **[A]** of a proper type -- i.e. of the `REQ` archetype,
   and
    **[B]** in a proper state -- i.e. after POSACK'd `.connect( args.reqrep )`

---

4. Supposing your **`REQ`** has asked the **`REP`** counterparty to shoot a picture and it does shoot a picture, it is outside of your local-process' control, whether the remote process(es) will or will not report such event also on any other messaging facility ( here, the `PUB`, as per item 1. above ) and thus a **`SUB`** may, but need not, receive any such notification automatically.

---

### Summary:

Having observed this mechanism to work, which constitutes a positive acknowledgement of the higher-layer services to process a JSON/ZeroMQ message-delivery the ZeroMQ API does not ignore anything on it's own, Q.E.D.

( In case your design needs a truly low-level access to services exposed by Canon onto USB-serial comms, [may be interested in Python module for this level of detail](https://pythonhosted.org/canon-remote/) ).